# Python: How do I create a code that loops through csv files in a folder

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, directory, export-to-csv

I trying to create a python code that goes to this folder I made on my laptop that has csv files and then loops through all the csv files then puts them all into a user-specified folder. This is all I got so far and I need help finishing up this code. I tried running this code and nothing happen. If anyone has an easier way to create this code that will be great as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r"C:\Users\Documents\Practicefolder1\*.csv"
for Tname in glob.glob(path):
    print(Tname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the files so that the file path reflects the appropriate directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

# The folder that the files will be moved to 
user_specified_folder = input('Please specify the folder to put the files in')

path = r'C:\Users\Documents\Practicefolder1\*.csv'

for Tname in glob.glob(path):

    # get the name of the file itself
    file_name = os.path.basename(Tname)

    # get a new file name for the new path
    new_file_name = os.path.join(user_specified_folder,file_name)

    # rename the file so that it is in the appropriate directory
    os.rename(Tname, new_file_name);
```